# ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, arm, cross-platform, bitbake

I am cross compiling an applicantion for arm in yocto build using bitbake. It's compiling fine but linking fails with below error.

```
/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/5.3.0/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
```

It also failed to link other files crti.o and crtbegin.o. I am not sure which dir needs to be added in LDFLAGS. Is it looking for arm toolchain lib dir or gcc lib dir?

Comment: Why don't you just try and search for the file in question?  On my PC (different toolschain) it's in {...}\arm-unknown-linux-gnu\sys-root\usr\lib\crt1.o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try a simple puts("Hello world") compiling with cc hello.c (no other options). If still have same issue most likely your toolchain is wrongly installed, else, check the linker options, may you are setting to not find standard libraries.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Compiler was looking for library files in standard path /usr/lib/ instead of toolchain's /usr/lib dir. Given --sysroot=${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/ which in turn helps to find the target path.